# Is it worth swapping two front-wheel hubs?

Tags: hub, rims

I have an old Bontrager Select rim with cartridge bearings and a newer Syncros Race 27 with loose ball bearings.

Both are 20 spoke, would it be worth it to swap the hubs? Or would it even be possible?

[image]

Comment: What do you hope to gain?  Is the loose bearing hub worn in the bearing race cups and/or cones?   I'd suggest you ride the lighter of the two wheels, and save the other one as an at-home spare.  Don't bother rebuilding them unless there's something significant to be gained.

Comment: The Bontrager wheel is the worn one, specially cracks forming in the rim, I was told that non-loose hubs are better in the long run than loose due to maintenance and them being sealed. If it is as complicated as Nathan suggests then it is not worth it as the loose bearing hubs are fairly new and show no real sign of wear.

Comment: Hubs with loose ball bearings are lighter, easier to service and more durable against lateral loads unless you have conical cartridge bearings. There's a reason why manufacturers like Shimano and Campagnolo choose loose balls.

Comment: There is no such thing as a sealed bearing.  There are simply bearings with seals - the difference being sealed can't leak and seals do eventually leak.  Consider a "sealed bearing" analogous to a "sealed jar of homemade jam" which will totally keep water out, but won't roll very well.    Retire the cracked wheel, and ride the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Worth it" is opinion-based, but no, probably not.

Possible, yes, but it's more technical than it might appear, and much more complex than building normal wheels, because the Bontrager wheel in the pic has paired spokes and the other does not. Normal hubs have spoke holes on the two flanges that are interleaved evenly with one another, to match the evenly spaced holes on the rim. Hubs for paired spokes have holes on one flange staggered a certain amount ahead of the other, also to match the holes in the rim. That's why your radial paired spoke wheel has spokes that still all radiate outward from the center of the hub.

If you were to do what you propose with these two hubs, you wouldn't be able to use the standard spoke length calculation formula. You'd have to do some measuring/math and rework the formula for the unusual spoke/hub angles that would result from doing this. You'd then be left with double-grooved hubs because the spokes wouldn't fall along the same path as original on either, which is never a good thing but should be avoided at all costs on radial wheels, because it sometimes makes the flanges blow up.

(Also, if it's not obvious, even if not for the issue of one being paired spoke, you'd still only physically be able to swap just the hubs and re-use the spokes if the hubs were close enough to the same dimensions, which they may or may not be, and that's putting aside all cautions against re-using spokes.)